# Rename Account Name Field label on Contract Standard Object

Tags: contracts, label

Can we update Account Name Label on the Contract Standard Object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow following steps:

1. From setup, Navigate to `App Setup` -> `Customize` -> `Tab Names and Labels` -> `Rename Tabs and Labels`.
2. Click on edit on Account in *Standard Tabs*, and go to `Step 2. Enter the new field labels`.
3. From there you can override label for `Account Name`.

Adding screenshot:
[image]

---

**Note: This would be change the label for Account Name in all the Lookup fields.**

Answer (score 1):

The field `Account Name` derives it's name from the `Account` object itself. So in order to change the field name, you'd have to change the name of the object.

To do this, go to:

> Setup > Tab Names and Labels > Rename Tabs and Labels

Then by Tab Name "Accounts", click "Edit" and enter the singular and plural name.

This will then reflect in the Account field name in the `Contract` object.