# Field Label change is not reflecting on Contact object

Tags: custom-field, checkbox

I have a checkbox field on the contact object that should be reading ‘Email Opt Out’. 
[image]

However, this is still what the field looks like on the actual contact page. 
[image]

The Field Name “HasOptedOutOfEmail” has not changed, just the Field Label. Any ideas as to why this is not updating or how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

This is a standard field (you can tell by the suffix, anything ending with `__c` is a custom field). You can't change the API Name of a Standard field. You can change the label, but not the API Name.

You could create your own custom field, and use that instead, which would let you name it whatever you want, but that comes with its own problems (getting the data back to the opt out standard field, having two fields doing the same thing, managing layouts, reports, etc).

I'd ask yourself why you need the API Name to be different. No end-user sees the API Name, just code, and developers.

Comment: Thanks. I agree I don't need the API to be different. Then, I am wondering why the field reads "Sales Email Unsubscribe" rather than "Email Opt Out."

Comment: Someone changed the label for the standard field. You can change it back, or just leave it. Its a little confusing to see in the setup, since they use the "real" field label and not the one you've given it. See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149286/rename-account-name-field-label-on-contract-standard-object) for an example of how to get to the right spot in setup.